# How to set rotation metadata flag for mp4 using ffmpeg libs

Tags: android, ffmpeg

We know that `MediaRecorder` has a funcion "[setOrientationHint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setOrientationHint%28int%29)" to set a rotation flag on the video file. I wonder how I can make the same effect using libavcodec, libavfilter, etc.